# Erro Firebase Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Estava configurando meu app para se conectar ao firebase mas toda vez que coloco no `build.grandle(Module: app)`

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
```

No meu app ocorre o erro abaixo:

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0] C:\Users\Gustavo.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6cfe46f408152b0cf1be5d6c31bb25ab\firebase-iid-19.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
>           Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
>               or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
>               or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.iid" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Comment: Ola @gustavo, o erro diz que o pacote `com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0` requer o **minSdkVersion >= 16** e seu projeto esta configurado com o **minSdkVersion=15** -- [Android Developers #Especificar requisitos de nível de API](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning#minsdkversion)

Answer (score -1):

Erro falha na fusão do manifesto: uses-sdk: minSdkVersion 15 não pode ser menor que a versão 16 declarada na biblioteca. Tente o seguinte:
vá até Grandle Script > build.gradle(Module:app), abra o arquivo e altere manualmente **minSdkVersion** de 15 para 16.

Comment: Olá Jonathan, tudo bem? Como você está levantando questões sobre a dúvida, procure fazer isso no comentário e deixar a resposta como uma solução objetiva e definitiva. Abraços!